# How to get the headers in a grid to copy to the clipboard

Tags: vb6

I'm using vb6, SQL Server2008, and ComponentOne Objects. I'm using the following code to copy the grid results to the clipboard:

```
Set rs = AdoMain.Recordset.Clone
  For Each row In GridMain.SelBookmarks
    rs.Bookmark = row
    'For col = gridMain.SelStartCol To gridMain.SelEndCol
    For Col = 0 To 15
      strTemp = strTemp & rs(Col).Value & vbTab
    Next Col
    strTemp = strTemp & vbCrLf
  Next row

  Clipboard.Clear
  Clipboard.SetText strTemp, vbCFText
```

This portion works great for the "body" of the grid, however I cannot get the grid headers to copy. Any help?

Comment: How is that question related to the fact that your data source is sql server? This is clearly something you do in your VB6 code. The source of the data is irrelevant. You should use a for loop over the grid columns and get the column headers from the grid itself.

Comment: I wasn't sure what would be relevant to the next person to read the question. So Included the sources as well. Rather a little too much than not enough info. In reply to you, I am working on exactly that as we speak, but going through the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS usage.

Comment: You should know that grid headers might be different then the column names. Perhaps irrelevant in your case, but I would suggest to still keep that in mind.

Comment: @Obfuscated, is the gridMain control is MSFlexGrid ?

Comment: It sounds like something similar from ComponentOne.  Sadly hardly anyone uses those by comparison with stock VB6 controls, so getting useful feedback might take a while here.  Better asked at ComponentOne's own support forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Name of **recordset** column use:

```
rs(col).Field.Name
```

but if you want the Header of **GridMain** column you should use

```
GridMain.Columns(col).Caption
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSFlexGrid, I think this will work:

```
With GridMain
    'select entire grid
    .Select .FixedRows, .FixedCols, .Rows - 1, .Cols - 1
    'copy selection to clipboard
    .Copy
End With
```